# Post To LinkedIn Groups as A Different User

Tags: asp.net, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I've an ASP.NET website with job openings ,

I want to allow users in my website to publish specific jobs to groups I manage on LinkedIn using MY LI user, and that the login process will be completely invisible to them, and they will only decide which group and which job to publish.

My question is if this is possible? using which LinkedIn API and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research and another question posted here, it is not a main feature of LinkedIn API.

Thus, unless using a specialized API, it's not possible.